# How do I make devise login/signup views work within jquery tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, tabs, devise

Inside my home page index view (.../app/views/home/index.html.haml), I have

```
#tabs
%ul
  %li= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, :remote => true
  %li= link_to "Log In",  new_user_session_path :remote => true

:coffeescript
  jQuery -> 
  $("#tabs").tabs()
```

Inside my devise new view (.../app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.html), I have

```
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :email
    %br/
    = f.email_field :email
  %p
    = f.label :password
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password
  %p
    - if devise_mapping.rememberable?
      = f.check_box :remember_me
      = f.label :remember_me
  %p
    = f.submit "Sign in"
```

The issue I am having is the application layout file is getting loaded into the tabs. I need to exclude it from being loaded.

I am currently using the default devise controller for sessions so cannot easily pass nil to the layout option when render is called.

Should I be using a partial in the link_to method? If so, how do I specify the syntax so it actually uses the devise session controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, which is quite simple:

Inside the .../config/application.rb file, add

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout nil
  Devise::RegistrationsController.layout nil
end
```